# How to manage gRPC server channel within a spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, grpc-java

I have a setup which has a spring-boot application and gRPC server. gRPC server has written in NodeJS and deployed in a separate server. In my spring-boot app, there is an endpoint which accepts a request object and delegate it to the gRPC server.

Question:

1) In this scenario, do I need to create rGPC channel for each incoming http request? *(which sounds not efficient)*

2) or do I have one channel created at the initialization of the spring-boot application?

In the 2) solution, how do I manage when the gRPC server is down and need to fetch the new URI from the eureka server?

Here is the [gRPC channel creation in spring-boot](https://github.com/JudeNiroshan/audit-server/blob/8e13e2131708137cf57104c1ec307c03bd3d4388/src/main/java/com/logger/rest/auditserver/mediator/GrpcMediator.java#L42).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2) is the way to go. To address the server down case, you can check the channel state (`io.grpc.ManagedChannel.getState(boolean)`) before forwarding the incoming http request to the gRPC server and if it's not `READY` then call your `initCommunicationChannel()` after suitably refactoring it so it can be called multiple times.

Alternatively you can implement a Name resolver plugin (https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/naming.md) which simply calls `eurekaClient.getApplication("logger-app").getInstances()` to return resolved addresses which are then used by a client side load balancing policy (https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/load-balancing.md).